# C# WCF without service reference

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I don't have any idea how to use WCF without add it to project using service reference in C#. I can't use service reference because my project haven't this option. Can someone tell my what i should to do?
WSDL which I will use have methods: Login, Logout, GetData, GetDetails, GetCaptcha, CheckCaptcha.

I try this solution but I have problem with ServiceContract. I can't use this type...

```
 BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
 EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("www");
 ChannelFactory<ServiceContract> factory = new ChannelFactory<ServiceContract>(binding, address);
 ServiceContract channel = factory.CreateChannel();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to adding a service reference is generating a proxy client using [SvcUtil.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe)

In [Visual Studio command prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs) you can generate a proxy as follows:

```
svcutil http://localhost/service.svc /t:code /out:ServiceProxy.cs /config:ServiceProxy.config
```

You can then add the generated proxy class and configuration to your project and start using the client.

Comment: Okey. I have another question. What i should to do when i have a .Net Core project and I want to change message encoding to MTOM?

Comment: You can use [dotnet-svcutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide) for .NET core and .NET standard projects. Once generated you can update the configuration to use [MTOM message encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/mtom-encoding). Edit: it looks like MTOM message encoding is [not supported in WCF for .NET core](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1810)